# Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate GenriDAO

Here is my code::

```
 private Class<T> persistentClass;
 public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
         return persistentClass;
 }
 public GenericHibernateDAO(Class<T> persistentClass ){
         this.persistentClass=persistentClass;
 }
 public T findById(long id) {
         SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
         Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         Transaction transaction = null;

         T entity=null;
         try {
                 transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                 entity=(T)session.get(getPersistentClass(), id);
                 //        transaction.commit();
         } catch (HibernateException e) {
         //        transaction.rollback();
                 e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
         //        transaction = null;
         }
         return entity;
 }
```

}

When i commit the transaction and try to access the attributes on the object(i.e pojo) it will give the hibernate exception "no session"  or session closed

if m not not commiting its work fine.
but the problem is session remains open.

What are the ways to access that entity ???

Comment: Please format the code when you post it (I have done it this time)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps : http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects

```
public abstract class GenericHibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable>
        implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> persistentClass;
    private Session session;

    public GenericHibernateDAO() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
     }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setSession(Session s) {
        this.session = s;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        if (session == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Session has not been set on DAO before usage");
        return session;
    }

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T findById(ID id, boolean lock) {
        T entity;
        if (lock)
            entity = (T) getSession().load(getPersistentClass(), id, LockMode.UPGRADE);
        else
            entity = (T) getSession().load(getPersistentClass(), id);

        return entity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return findByCriteria();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findByExample(T exampleInstance, String[] excludeProperty) {
        Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
        Example example =  Example.create(exampleInstance);
        for (String exclude : excludeProperty) {
            example.excludeProperty(exclude);
        }
        crit.add(example);
        return crit.list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T makePersistent(T entity) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public void makeTransient(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    public void flush() {
        getSession().flush();
    }

    public void clear() {
        getSession().clear();
    }

    /**
     * Use this inside subclasses as a convenience method.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) {
        Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
        for (Criterion c : criterion) {
            crit.add(c);
        }
        return crit.list();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate by default is **lazy**. Most probably the attributes you are getting are being loaded lazily. Whenever the session is open you can access the properties as Hibernate fetches these properties as and when initialized/accessed.
e.g :

```
public class Person{ 
  private  Set<Child> children;

  public Set<Child> getChildren(){
          return children;
  }
  public void setChildren(Set<Child> p0){
      this.children=p0;
  }
}
```

Here when you load the instance of a person the children collection isn't loaded eagerly. Hibernate fetches them when you access it.
If the session is closed it throws a `LazyInitializationException`

Have a look concepts of ***Lazy Loading*** and ***Eager loading*** in Hibernate
also for starters try to glance over the ***Open Session In View Pattern*** if you are using Hibernate in a web application.